# how can get post value with key in dajngo

Tags: django

how can access post values with index as key in view.py in dajngo
I need split values based on same key

This is my post value

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b5cJ9z5zqWdMrUN8wyUvpQMjt7KeEy1bfWwjzia1KajUHWfI9OvXvxtOLNcB0HLW'], 'product_id': ['3'], 'include_product_id[x_808903]': ['1'], 'index_val': ['x_808903', 'x_152554'], 'product_name[]': ['ISOPURE AMINOS-(ALPINE PUNCH-10.05 OZ)', 'SYNTHA-6 EDGE-(CHOCOLATE MILKSHAKE-48 SERVING)'], 'product_qty[x_808903]': ['10'], 'product_price[x_808903]': ['1'], 'total_amount[x_808903]': ['10'], 'include_product_id[x_152554]': ['3'], 'product_qty[x_152554]': ['2'], 'product_price[x_152554]': ['2'], 'total_amount[x_152554]': ['4'], 'submit': ['Submit']}>
```

I am trying this way to access but its not working

```
  for index in index_val:
    include_product_id =request.POST['include_product_id'+[index]]
    product_price =request.POST['product_price'+[index]]
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: are you trying to loop a query dict right?

Comment: Try to construct the dynamic index like this : `dyna_index = f"include_product_id[{index}]"`  **( I use python f-string )**. And after get it from POST values : `include_product_id = request.POST[dyna_index]`. Let us know the rest.

Comment: Thank so much @Rvector This way i can get my expected output

Comment: From what I can see (CSRF token indicates usual django forms), your problem can be solved with `ModelFromSet`s. or when working with foreign keys (related objects) `InlineFormSet`s (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Answer (score 0):

================= Your dictionary is here =================

```
my_dict = {
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['b5cJ9z5zqWdMrUN8wyUvpQMjt7KeEy1bfWwjzia1KajUHWfI9OvXvxtOLNcB0HLW'], 
'product_id': ['3'], 
'include_product_id[x_808903]': ['1'], 
'index_val': ['x_808903', 'x_152554'], 
'product_name[]': ['ISOPURE AMINOS-(ALPINE PUNCH-10.05 OZ)','SYNTHA-6 EDGE-(CHOCOLATE MILKSHAKE-48 SERVING)'], 
'product_qty[x_808903]': ['10'], 
'product_price[x_808903]': ['1'], 
'total_amount[x_808903]': ['10'], 
'include_product_id[x_152554]': ['3'], 
'product_qty[x_152554]': ['2'], 
'product_price[x_152554]': ['2'], 
'total_amount[x_152554]': ['4'], 
'submit': ['Submit']

}
```

======== Solution - 1 ==================

==== get all keys and values form dictionary (here values contain list) ====

```
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    print(key," = ",value)
```

======== Output - 1 ========
[image]

======== Solution - 2 ==================

==== get all keys and values form dictionary (here values iterate from list) =====

```
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    for j in value:
        print(key," = ",j)
```

======== Output - 2 ========
[image]